# cut off last rune in UTF string

Tags: utf-8, go

How to cut off last rune in UTF string?
This method is obviously incorrect:

```
package main

import ("fmt"
 "unicode/utf8")

func main() {
    string := "你好"
    length := utf8.RuneCountInString(string)
    // how to cut off last rune in UTF string? 
    // this method is obviously incorrect:
    withoutLastRune := string[0:length-1]
    fmt.Println(withoutLastRune)
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ugeMExeedT)

Comment: See [The Go Blog - Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings) to see why your attempt is incorrect. https://play.golang.org/p/_odF4J6LSb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost,

utf8 package has a function to decode the last rune in a string which also returns its length. Cut that number of bytes off the end and you are golden:

```
str := "你好"
_, lastSize := utf8.DecodeLastRuneInString(str)
withoutLastRune := str[:len(str)-lastSize]
fmt.Println(withoutLastRune)
```

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/fQTI97H98Q)

Answer (score 0):

Using DecodeLastRuneInString is the best answer.  I'll just note that if you prize simpler code over run time efficiency, you can do

```
    s := []rune(str)
    fmt.Println(string(s[:len(s)-1]))
```

Comment: I'll add a note to your note :) that this is O(n) and allocates and copies whereas using `utf8.DecodeLastRuneInString` is O(1) and does not allocate or copy. The later can be done [in two lines that to me look just as simple](https://play.golang.org/p/_odF4J6LSb) as your two lines.